# Why did the Highcharts export menu disappear when I moved the button?

Tags: css, highcharts

I removed the title from a few charts (actually I passed in an empty string for the title) and had to add blank space back into the top of the charts to pull the export menu out from among the plotted data. I got the button positioned satisfactorily, but then I'd click on it and... no menu. It's in the DOM, it's even being toggled correctly, but invisible. Huh?

Here's what I added to the chart (obviously other options as well, this is just the relevant changes). `title_pad` is a variable holding the pixel height I added to the top of the chart:

```
{ 
  chart: {
    height: [previousHeight] + title_pad,
    spacingTop: title_pad 
  },
  exporting: {
    buttons: {
      contextButton: {
        y: "-" + title_pad
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After bashing at this for most of an hour, I realized the problem was that I was creating the negative number in the `y` attribute by concatenating the value into a string, thus generating a string `"-30"`. This apparently mucked with Highcharts' export menu positioning in an unfriendly way, even though it "worked" for positioning the button.

I replaced that concatenated string with `0 - title_pad` (i.e. a calculation which would produce a negative integer) and the menu reappeared.